# Slow iOS Performance due to titleForHeaderInSection

Tags: ios, swift, performance, uitableview

I have an app that counts calories.  Users input their calories (each bit of food becomes one row in a TableView.  Each section represents one day.

I have a section header that adds all the calories from that day.

Now I have a years worth of inputs the performance of loading the app is slow (takes about 5 seconds).  I used instruments and the method responsible is titleForHeaderInSection.  The issue I have found is this method is called for every single section when the tableview loads (not just the sections displayed).

Is there anyway to get around this?  I am keen to show daily totals.

Comment: What are you doing in that code?  I presume you are calculating the daily totals. Why don't you calculate the daily total whenever the data for a day changes and store that in your database rather than calculating it each time.

Comment: You shouldn't do anything during UITableView data source methods other than preparing the views and returning them. Any calculations should be performed before or asynchronously.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Xcode. No need to keep adding that tag.

Answer (score 0):

If your calculation of the title is a little "expensive", then you need a way to defer that calculation. There is no good way to know when `titleForHeaderInSection` is being called to really show the title and when it is being called just to setup the table view.

One solution would be to replace the use of `titleForHeaderInSection` with `viewForHeaderInSection` and `heightForHeaderInSection`.

The trick will be to only set the header view's text when the header view is actually being added to the table view. This can be done in the `willMove(toSuperview:)` method of your custom header view class. If the superview is non-nil, then the view is being added to its parent view. You'll need a way to use that method to actually do the calculation for the header's text.

As pointed out in the comments, the other possible solution is to calculate each day's total just once and store the value. Then when loading the data in the table view, you don't need to do any calculations. Just use the predetermined value.